# Testing that Django templates render correctly

Tags: python, django, testing, pytest-django

I have an index.html that includes a nav.html which has a url tag that points to a rout name that doesn't exist. When I run the index view test the response code is 200 and the test passes. If I `manage.py runserver` and navigate to the index in my browser I get a NoReverseMatch error message page. When I remove the include from index.html and put the contents of nav.html directly into index.html the test fails as expected.

**How do I write a test that will catch the problem in the included template?**

nav.html

```
{% url 'project:wrong_name' %}
```

index.html

```
{% include 'project/nav.html' %}
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'project/index.html')
```

tests.py

```
def test_index_view(client):
    response = client.get(reverse('project:index')
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

settings.py

```
...
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
...
```

virtualenv (abbreviated):

```
python==3.6.1
Django==1.11
pytest-django==3.1.2
```

Comment: Do you have `DEBUG` enabled or not? If DEBUG is off all the exceptions raised during rendering of `include` will be silenced by default.

Comment: I have tried running the tests with DEBUG on and off and get the same results.

Comment: Show your `TEMPLATES` conf in `settings.py` if you have defined.

Comment: TEMPLATES added to question.

Comment: Why not test the response content in the included template?

Comment: I don't want to write tests for every little thing in all the included templates. I just want to know that nothing is broken.

Comment: Note that the behaviour is [deprecated in Django 1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.11/#id2), and in Django 2.1 exceptions will be raised when rendering `{% include %}` tags. Until then you could either write a test that checks for expected content from the include tag (you don't need to check for every little thing, one item from the include tag is enough), or you could try to detect the deprecation warning when the exception is swallowed.